# UIImage+AFNetworking puts another image on top of loaded image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks

I am using `setImageWithURLRequest` method to asynchronously download images to customized UIImageViews and put a placeholder while image is being downloaded. The problem is that this category somehow puts downloaded image on the top of my customized UIImageView. It is impossible to debug the issue with view hierarchy debugger, as these additional unneeded images just don't appear there at all. Here is the code I'm using for the request:

```
ExhibitImageView *newExhibitImageView = [[ExhibitImageView alloc] initWithFrame:_pictureScrollView.bounds];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://uddddpload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Karl_Brullov_-_The_Last_Day_of_Pompeii_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/1280px-Karl_Brullov_-_The_Last_Day_of_Pompeii_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholderImage"];


__weak ExhibitImageView *weakExhibitImageView = newExhibitImageView;

[newExhibitImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:placeholderImage success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
    weakExhibitImageView.image = image;
    [weakExhibitImageView setNeedsLayout];
    [weakExhibitImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
} failure:nil];
```

Then I use some code to put this custom view to a scrollview (this may be related to the issue):

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
       CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenRect.size.height);
CGFloat totalWidth = page * screenWidth;
frame.origin.x = totalWidth;
newExhibitImageView.frame = frame;

[_pictureScrollView addSubview:newExhibitImageView];
```

This what I get in application:
[image: Application (Simulator)]
And this is how it looks in View Hierarchy debugger (Xcode) - totally correct and how it has to be:

---

[image: View Hierarchy debugger]

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `clipsToBounds = YES;` property on the custom views solved the issue. Seems that AFNetworking was just overriding defaults. The only question arises - why I was not able to see this issue using View Hierarchy Debugger?

Comment: AFNetworking doesn't override anything. `clipsToBounds` is false by default.

Comment: It worked before I implemented AFNetworking with the same picture.